# Difference between object_id and regular id

Tags: facebook-fql

I noticed that several fql tables have an object_id as well as a regular id. For instance, the photo table has both the object_id and a pid. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: Good question.  Pretty badly documented... out of interest is there any difference in the value when you query it?  I notice that in the docs, one is a string and the other is an integer value

Comment: the normal id can be accessed via graph api, the object_id is that same object but can be accessed via fql for graph.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can append the object_id to `www.facebook.com/` to use as a link to the actual picture in facebook.